# Cisco ASA 5525 VPN authentication with gmail account

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn

I'm wondering if it's possible to setup a VPN authentication to Cisco asa firewall by using gmail account?
Each time me or any of my users want to use VPN we could use our gmail credentials and it would authenticate against google server? Is that possible?
Would I need to setup a proxy server to handle this?
I'm still thinking about this and I'm not sure if this is doable. If anyone has any experience or knows how and if this could be achieved please share with me you

Comment: Google doesn't provide RADIUS or LDAP, so you'd have to hack together your own web-to-RADIUS system. (multi-factor authentication would be a problem)

Comment: David, This would not be possible without some kind of programming on your part. As mentioned by Ricky Beam, Google doesn't provide `RADIUS` or `LDAP` therefor you would need to create your own system for implementing that - how you would go about doing it is not something I can answer. Have you tried Googling this and seeing if anyone else has tried to implement such a thing? I don't believe I've ever seen anyone do that. Why is it necessary for you to have such a thing?

Comment: Thanks for telling me this. I don't necessarily need this. This was just an idea my manager and I had and after extensive googling I couldn't find anything like that implemented by anyone. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, no, this isn't possible.  However, you can at least set up your VPN to use 2FA if you want it to be more secure.  Duo is what one of our contracts uses to accomplish this for IRS compliance.  It's essentially just the Google Authenticator API in a different wrapper, and you generate your OTP on the Duo app on either a computer or phone.